# Decaying behavior of $g \in C^{\infty}[c,\infty]$ such that $\int_c^{\infty} g <\infty$ with $c>0$ and $g$ decreasing

Tags: real-analysis, integration, probability-theory, derivatives, probability-distributions

Suppose for $g \in C^{\infty}[c,\infty]$ with $c>0$ that
$$
\int_c^{\infty} g(x) dx <\infty,
$$
and $g$ is monotonically decreasing.
Then is it for some $M>0$ and $p<0$, 
$$
|g'(x)| < x^p
$$
for all $x >M$?

What if $g$ is a probability distribution which is piece-wisely $C^{\infty}$? Can we say about exponential decaying behavior of $g$?

How about multidimensional case?

Comment: Consider an integrable smooth $h\geqslant 0$ with peaks of exponentially growing height and $f(x) = \int_x^{+\infty} h(t)\,dt$.

Comment: Clearly no such result can hold. Think of a function alternating between intervals where it is constant and intervals where its slope is $-1$. If the sum of the lengthes of the intervals where it decreases is finite, the function can stay positive. Now, smoothen everything to get some $C^\infty$ counterexample.

Comment: Guys, sorry but I didn't mention that $g$ is monotonically decreasing in the first posting though I mentioned it on the title.

Comment: Since $g'\le 0,$ the inequality is obvious, but you probably meant $|g'|.$

Comment: @zhw. Ah ye. Thanks for feedback. You are right.